# TeamViewer 11 won't run on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, teamviewer

After installing TeamViewer 11 on Ubuntu Desktop 64-bit 16.04, I get the error:

> Verification of your teamviewer version failed, Teamviewer will quit for security reason. Please reinstall teamviewer

I have uninstalled and purged several times, and I always get the same error on install.
TeamViewer 10 works 100% fine. I need version 11 as clients have upgraded.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I suspect that Teamviewer checks a chain of certificates, and that Teamviewer 11 needs a different CA provider from version 10.  Is the package `ca-certificates` on your system the latest version?

Comment: It is a complete new, fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 from cd.

Comment: All the updates are done and the install processes through like it has worked. I followed the instructions for command line install from the Teamviewer website.

Comment: Also, today at work i did a fresh install of 16.04 on a different HP pc. It presented with the exact same error.

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug with Teamviewer.

Comment: The same problem here, after upgrade (not fresh install) to 16.04. During the upgrade Ubuntu suggested to turn of UEFI secure boot in order to allow third party drivers to work. I wonder whether it may be related to the TeamViewer.

Comment: Can someone disprove this idea above - e.g. someone for whom it does not work even without UEFI, or someone for whom it works with UEFI?

Comment: Update - I installed a fresh copy of 15.10, then installed Teamviewer 11. everything worked perfect. I then did the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and everything is still running fine. The end result is what i wanted with latest 16.4 ubuntu and latest teamviewer 11.

Comment: Update - This is a know bug with Ubuntu 16.04 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-deb-software-install-error . There is currently NO FIX

Answer (score 35):

As first, remove the actually broken Teamviewer installation in a terminal () by:

```
apt-get purge teamviewer
```

If this does not want to work you can as well do this with `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -r --force teamviewer
```

After that make sure you delete any leftovers from your user directory, i.e. `~/.local/share/teamviewer11`, `~/.config/temaviewer` and `/etc/teamviewer`:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/teamviewer11
rm -r ~/.config/teamviewer
sudo rm -r /etc/teamviewer
```

Now that this is out of the way, you do an update and an upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxtst6:i386 ca-certificates
```

Now download the Teamviewer package from their website ([download-link](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb)) and install it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb
```

After that it should run start normaly. If you not see teamviewer yet in the dash search check `/usr/share/applications` directory if the shortcut `teamviewer-teamviewer11.desktop` exists. If not create one by

```
sudoedit teamviewer-teamviewer11.desktop
```

And pasting (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) the following in:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=TeamViewer 11
Comment=TeamViewer Remote Control Application
Exec=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
Icon=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/desktop/teamviewer.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
#Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
```

It should show up in dash at least after a reboot. Meanwhile you can firstly start your new installed Teamviewer vie the terminal by:

```
teamviewer &
disown
```

Now you can lock it at least already onto your launcher if you wish to do so.

Comment: Thank you.. After searching for 2 days this finally worked for me. I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64-bit). I followed everything you said and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I found a "solution":

first I purged teamviewer `sudo apt-get purge teamviewer`
then deleted `~\.local\share\TeamViewer11`

then update ubuntu, reinstall teamviewer, and it works

Comment: Last direcory now  /teamviewer12 not /TeamViewer11 ! not first capitalize!