# teamviewer ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit, teamviewer, multiarch

When I follow that advices:
[TeamViewer 11 won't run on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764228/teamviewer-11-wont-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit)
I get following errors:

```
al@alpc:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 286983 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (11.0.57095) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libdbus-1-3.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libfontconfig1.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libsm6.
```

But when I try to install missed libs I see:

```
al@alpc:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdbus-1-3 is already the newest version (1.10.6-1ubuntu3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Depends: libsystemd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 teamviewer:i386 : Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And so on for all required libs. Trying to fix dependencies didn't helps me:

```
al@alpc:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  appstream dns-root-data dnsmasq-base ethtool gdbserver gnome-software gnome-software-common iputils-arping libappstream3 libasound2:i386 libbabeltrace1 libc6-dbg libfreetype6:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgtkspell3-3-0 libice6:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libndp0 libnetfilter-conntrack3 libpng12-0:i386 libqmi-glib1 libqmi-proxy libx86-1
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-31-generic mobile-broadband-provider-info
  modemmanager plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils procmail pyotherside python-kerberos python3-checkbox-support python3-guacamole python3-jinja2 python3-padme python3-plainbox python3-pyparsing
  python3-xlsxwriter qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qmlscene qtdeclarative5-dev-tools sensible-mda usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data vbetool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teamviewer:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

When I try to run teamviewer:

```
al@alpc:~/Downloads$ teamviewer 

Init...
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {4315d437-5b8c-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {4315d437-5b8c-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4315d437-5b8c-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x3
wine: configuration in '/home/al/.local/share/teamviewer11' has been updated.
Launching TeamViewer ...
Starting network process (no daemon)
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Network process already started (or error)
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

About libdbus it seems that this library is installed:

```
al@alpc:~/Downloads$ sudo find / -iregex ".*libdbus-1.so.3.*"
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
```

How to fix that? What is the problem. I completely confused.

Comment: What happens if you just double-click on the .deb file? gdebi should open it, and it'll tell you if there are missing dependencies. I recently installed teamviewer_11.0.52520_i386.deb without a problem. What is the output of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. Let me know. Cheers, Al