# TeamViewer 11 won't install on 16.10 64 bit

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, remote-desktop, 16.10

My Ubuntu doesn't want to install TeamViewer 11 again. :(
I had problems with sound - I tried to install Realtek HD Audio driver, but Ubuntu after installation and reboot forgot about sound chip on my motherboard and no sound was produced.
So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu (with saving my personal data including apps) using my USB Key.
Well - I had to install again GRUB Customizer, Steam and more recent apps that I use and they worked perfectly.
Without TeamViewer...
TeamViewer dropped some problems with packages not installed, but after, when I wrote to terminal commend

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

it installs these packages, uninstalling also TeamViewer.
Now when I try to install 32bit version, terminal dropps me this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 179972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (11.0.67687) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
teamviewer:i386 depends on libpng12-0.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386
```

On 64bit version I see this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer.
(Reading database ... 179972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_11.0.67687_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (11.0.67687) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
teamviewer depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.
  teamviewer depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer
```

So... what can I do?
On Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS worked fine.

I used [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764228/teamviewer-11-wont-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit).

Comment: I don't think TeamViewer supports 16.10 yet.

Comment: I thought so... But I found solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the solution for installing TeamViewer on 16.10.
I hope that this will work for all. 
When you see this error...

```
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 179972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (11.0.67687) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libpng12-0.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386
```

type `sudo apt-get install -f` and say "yes".
After that go to [this website](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpng12-0), download the package and install also from terminal using command

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_xxxxx_i386.deb
```

where `xxxxx` is the version of your libpng. I used the stable version 1.2.50-2+deb8u2.
After that again install TeamViewer and you will don't have errors. ;)
I hope that for everyone this solution will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use new [Teamviewer 12](https://www.teamviewer.com/latest-version), it doesn't have libpng12 dependency.