# How to install exact 11 version of team viewer on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, teamviewer

I need to install version 11 of teamviewer on ubuntu system . I have tried the solution in this question `http://askubuntu.com/questions/764228/teamviewer-11-wont-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit` but the problem is that when I download teamviewer from  any download link for teamviewer it always gives version 12, I really need version 11 as my team mates have version 11 on their systems. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to install version `11`:

1. Get *version 11*

   - the link will download the *[64 bit deb](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_11x/teamviewer_amd64.deb)* package
   - For *[32/64](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_11x/teamviewer_i386.deb)* bit version
2. Install:

   - `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.xxxxx_i386.deb`
3. Any issues with dependencies run this:

   - `sudo apt-get install -f`

**NOTE:**

```
Notes on Multiarch:

On newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7) 
teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the 
package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems. 
In this case you can use teamviewer_11.0.xxxxx_i386.deb instead.
```

For *multiarch* systems:

- In case you get the error **wrong architecture i386** you have to execute the following command lines as an administrator:

  ```
  dpkg --add-architecture i386
  apt-get update
  ```

Source:

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx#grafischeInstallation

Previous versions:

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/previous-versions/

Comment: It downloads version 12 :(

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: check it now just updated the link

Comment: dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer Getting this error

Comment: did you `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: How can I download teamviewer_11.0.xxxxx_i386.deb

Comment: let me add that link too.

Comment: yes i did sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: That would be so great sir :)

Comment: just added it see if that flies.

Comment: I can download it, but it doesn't start.

Comment: @stiv what are the error messages if any?

Comment: there are no error messages, it just doesn't start.