# Teamviewer 12 no GUI

Tags: 16.04, teamviewer

I've been using teamviewer on Ubuntu for a long time. Since I upgraded to version 12 it works ok for a couple of days, sometimes weeks and then suddenly it stops launching. I've managed at least three times to get it to work again uninstalling it an then removing every trace of it using locate command. This time that didn't work niether. The package is `Teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb` running on Ubuntu 16.04 x64, the same package was used successfully before. The log on `/var/log/teamviewer12` is:

```
cat /var/log/teamviewer12/TeamViewer12_Logfile.log 
2017/01/20 12:32:12.727  4003 4146104256 S   Logger started.
2017/01/20 12:32:12.728  4003 4146104256 S   Found 0 Minidump files ...
2017/01/20 12:32:12.728  4003 4146104256 S   Found 0 core dump files ...
2017/01/20 12:32:12.729  4003 4146104256 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_2
2017/01/20 12:32:12.729  4003 4146104256 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.729  4003 4146104256 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_1
2017/01/20 12:32:12.729  4003 4146104256 S+  Thread: IOServiceWorker_0_3
2017/01/20 12:32:12.730  4003 4146104256 S   systemd: logind service available
2017/01/20 12:32:12.731  4003 4146104256 S   systemd: New seat seat0 [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0, activeSession='c1', canGraphical=1, canTTY=1, canMultiSession=1]
2017/01/20 12:32:12.731  4003 4146104256 S+  DBus: optional property DefaultControlGroup not found
2017/01/20 12:32:12.731  4003 4146104256 S+  DBus: optional property KillProcesses not found
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S   SystemdSessionInfo: New session SystemdSessionInfo [id=c1 user=roni state=user active=1 reliable=1 infoId=0] [path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c1 TTY= seat=seat0 display=:0 vtnr=7 owner=[SysUser_Lin: roni [uid=1000, gid=1000 home=/home/roni gecos=roni,,, shell=/bin/bash]] idle=0(0) active=1 type=x11 class=user state=active timestamp=1484925236145766 service=lightdm-autologin defaultCG= leader=1161 audit=0 remote=0 rHost= rUser= killProc=0]
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by systemd [priority: 0]
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S   SysSessionInfoManager: Session Information provided by VT [priority: 2]
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S+  LateBinding [libX11.so.6]: Loaded library
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S   XSocket observer: watching /tmp/.X11-unix
2017/01/20 12:32:12.732  4003 4146104256 S   XSocket observer: adding XSession: 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.733  4003 4146104256 S   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 0 to info provider 'systemd'
2017/01/20 12:32:12.733  4003 4146104256 S   SysSessionInfoManager: assigned session 1000000 to info provider 'None'
2017/01/20 12:32:12.733  4003 4146104256 S   Starting as daemon
2017/01/20 12:32:12.734  4003 4146104256 S!  AsioSettings::FindExternalIP: found 0 external IPs instead of 1!
2017/01/20 12:32:12.735  4003 4146104256 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.735  4003 4146104256 S!  AsioSettings::FindExternalIP: found 0 external IPs instead of 1!
2017/01/20 12:32:12.736  4003 4146104256 S   Generating new RSA private/public key pair
2017/01/20 12:32:12.764  4003 4146104256 S   System uptime: 1105 seconds
2017/01/20 12:32:12.764  4003 4146104256 S   MachineID m=0 - 0



Start:              2017/01/20 12:32:12.765  (UTC-3:00)
Version:            12.0.71510 
ID:                 0
Loglevel:           Info (100)
License:            0
Server:             master10.teamviewer.com
IC:                 1454453726
CPU:                Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
CPU extensions:     h9
OS:                 Lx Ubuntu 16.04.1 LT (32-bit)
IP:                 192.168.0.105,10.8.0.1
MID:                1454453726_b3a82e9a_55cb09896d984250
MIDv:               0
Proxy-Settings:     Type=0 IP= User=

2017/01/20 12:32:12.765  4003 4146104256 S   RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2017/01/20 12:32:12.765  4003 4020218688 S   RemoteSettingsStore: Cleanup all policies.
2017/01/20 12:32:12.765  4003 4146104256 S   RemoteSettingsStoreListener: Establish connection.
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4020218688 S   RemoteSettingsStore::LoadLastReceivedPolicies : Storage Entry Remote_Settings_TVClientSetting_Policy empty
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4020218688 S   RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   Using IPC-Port 5939
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   Updated sessions: [ 0 C  roni ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   Updated sessions: [ 0 C  roni ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.766  4003 4146104256 S   UpdateResponseLinux: success 1 updated 0 rev 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.767  4003 4003433280 S   Using systemd-logind for suspend/resume monitoring
2017/01/20 12:32:12.767  4003 4003433280 S   Session login for session 0
2017/01/20 12:32:12.767  4003 4003433280 S   CTerminalServer::RepeatedlyCheckForUserLogin() Don't start GUI for session 0
```

Please Help!

Comment: Same problem!
I already purged and reinstalled several times, it works for some days and then the problem comes back..
Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem, I solved in this way, looking at `/home/user/.config/teamviewer/client.conf` the parameter  `[strng] FT_Start_Directories = ""` was ridiculously long and I simply deleted anything between the " " as many of the directories were not even in my computer. Now Teamviewer is back!

Comment: Actually, the folders that appear as parameters in the string you mention, are folders located in computers I've connected and shared files with. This means that the problem is caused when you share files with other computers.

Comment: Yes it's the same for me.. Should be a TW bug..

Comment: Yes, the same here, as @RoniBerezin mentioned I had some path from last file sharing with other computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My OS is **linux mint** and i solved the problem by the following:

1. `apt-get purge teamviewer`
2. `locate -e teamviewer`
3. remove all files and folders with name 'teamviewer' from step 2 except data disk or themes,
   e.g., /home/'youraccount'/.config/teamviewer, /home/'youraccount'/.config/teamviewer10...
4. download the newest teamviewer deb and install

I just solved the problem with above!

Reference:
[TeamViewer 11 won't run on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764228/teamviewer-11-wont-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit)