# Installing TeamViewer 11 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, teamviewer, libpng

fairly noobish to Linux, although I have a few machines with different distros to fiddle around with

Getting a server up and running with 20.04 LTS, and having issues with getting an older version of TeamViewer up and running.. I know there's some better alternatives, but I own a commercial license for Version 11 that I use for all my machines, and my clients.

I run into issues with teamviewer:i386 depending on libpng12-0.

I've tried following a variety of similar threads that are aimed at getting it running with [Linux v 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764228/teamviewer-11-wont-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit) and [Linux v18](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Team-Viewer-11-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/33334), but neither process appears replicable in v20

Not sure if logs are allowed, but I'll beg forgiveness if not - here's my output (user/machine names altered)

```
test@test:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.256402_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 197780 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_11.0.256402_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (11.0.256402) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libasound2.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libdbus-1-3.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libexpat1.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libfontconfig1.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libfreetype6.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0:i386 is not installed.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libsm6; however:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libxdamage1; however:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libxfixes3; however:

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386
test@test:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 198073 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:i386 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
```

Thanks, appreciate any guidance here!

Comment: If the above comment solve your problem let me know via a comment. Then I will convert the comment to a full answer. At that time you will be able to accept the answer as correct with the green check mark. This will help others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @user68186 If this is the case it would be easier for me to just reimage to v18 - I paid over 1k for the TV license and the current version is a monthly cost which I'm not eager to move over to.

Thanks for the advice, I suppose it could be considered an answer!

Comment: @karel I tried that too, but it seems the i386 files just aren't available for 20.04, so it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here - 1st is libpng12 package, 2nd is TeamViewer dependencies.

The first is fixable by installation [from PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/66509):

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb
sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb
```

and then you will be able to install TeamViewer:

```
sudo apt-get install ./teamviewer_11.0.256402_i386.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the first libpng12 file I've gotten to work, but I had to use Filezilla to get the deb into my directory as the apt-get you listed didn't work.

Here, the next oddity - this seems to have installed TeamViewer 15 as well as 11 - the former runs (but is useless to me as I don't have the supporting license, and 11 doesn't even start up.

Neither show up in Apps under Installed, and when I tried to remove them both so I could try and reinstall 11 on it's own, only 11 vanished, leaving 15 seeming impervious to removal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could fix with this: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-EN/How-to-use-the-TAR-package-for-Linux/ta-p/30664

first you must to enter in your teamviewer path:

```
cd /path-to-extracted-TAR/teamviewer/
```

and then run this:

```
./tv-setup checklibs
```

Install the missing dependencies if you have some and then run

```
./teamviewer
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't see this notification :/

I'm back to trying to get this working.. I used the sudo ./tv-setup install because my plan is to keep the Host version alive, and while there were no dependencies listed as required, it doesn't seem to run, launching it doesn't do anything (or appear to do anything)

Note that I can check the status of the daemon and it is indeed running.. but the app itself doesn't seem to launch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_11x/teamviewer_i386.deb

 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

 sudo apt install libc6:i386 libasound2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libsystemd0:i386

 wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb

 sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~eoan_i386.deb

 sudo dpkg -i ./teamviewer_i386.deb

 wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetype/libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb

 sudo apt install binutils -y

 tar -x ./libfreetype6_2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb    
    
 tar -xvf ./data.tar.xz
    
 sudo cp -r ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib
    
 sudo cp ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.12.1 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib
    
 sudo apt install lightdm -y
        During installation choose **lightdm** and OK
        This is because Ubuntu 20's default display manager is gmd3,
        and it doesn't allow incoming connections when you sing out.
        (when your screen is locked)

 sudo chmod 777 /etc/X11/default-display-manager

 sudo echo "/usr/bin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager

 sudo chmod 644 /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

And after doing all of the above, reboot.

Comment: While your answer might really help, it is also best to describe in a word or two what is going to happen, and what are you trying to do with all this instruction set, and why you suggested implementing it.

Comment: Wow, I have no clue how this comment sat here without notifying me for over a year, but I'll give this a shot, this is the first time I've had the "lightdm" part suggested as the reason it's not working.. Although it wasn't even running when launched, maybe this will still help (the machine I have for this is at the office where I'm not atm)