# How to remove app installed from terminal?

Tags: 20.04

This hearkens back to [my previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240669/installing-teamviewer-11-in-ubuntu-20-04) about trying to get TeamViewer up and running in 20.04 LTS.. I'm trying to get this desktop functional and connected via TV ver. 11, but unable to remove version 15 from my system.

It doesn't show up in Applications, and when I use grep to locate it, I can only find the older i386 version that won't launch. I can open version 15, but can't find where it's actually installed to.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt purge teamviewer*` might be enough to jar it loose.

Comment: That didn't work, but sudo apt-get purge teamviewer removed the i386 version

I am able to pull [these logs](https://file.io/ImndMOU6md4M) from Version 15 (the one I can't seem to remove) - do they give any information as to where the program might be stored or labelled?